# Swift 3, accessing user input Text Field values from ViewControler and used them in a model .swift file

Tags: ios, swift

This is my first question. I'm new to swift and programming in general so please don't laugh if I'm asking stupid question :)

So I hava a SettingsViewControler where users sets their values, lets say they set the temperature value. What i'm trying to do, is to take that temperature value that they input and pass it to my model.swift file, to introduce that value in the formula, to calculate the new value with the input temperature. I hope this make sense.

Is there a way to do that directly by calling the class form VC to the newData class that I created in model.swift file, or I should use some methods like UserDefaults to pass data.

Here is the code example:

First I created a Settings.swift file

```
      // Settings.swift file

import Foundation

class Settings {

var inputTemperature: Float = 0


init(inputTemperature: Float) {

    self.inputTemperature = inputTemperature
}

}
```

Here is the  Settings View Controller

```
  //Settings ViewCOntroller. swift file

import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var inputTemperatureTextField: UITextField!

var getTemp = Settings(inputTemperature: 72)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

func getValues() {

    getTemp.inputTemperature = (inputTemperatureTextField.text! as NSString).floatValue

}

 }else if textField == inputTemperatureTextField {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        getValues()


}
```

So now I have another Calculations.swift file where I want to get the inputTemperature value to use it in the formula

```
 //Calculation. swift file

import Foundation

class Calculations {

var inputA: Float = 0
var inputB: Float = 0
var resultC: Float =  0


init(inputA: Float, inputB: Float) {

    self.inputA = inputA
    self.inputB = inputB

   }

   // Here i want to add the temperature value 
   func calc() {

    resutC = inputA * inputC // * inputTemperature

   }
```

I want the get (inputTemperatureTextField.text! as NSString).floatValue value from SettingsView COntroller to introduce it in the formula located Calculation.swift file

Thanks

Comment: You can create an initializer in to get the temperature in your Model class and than make an instance of your model in viewController and pass the temperature in the initializer method.

Answer (score 0):

You should really post some of your code to give us some insight in what exactly it is you want. 
Lets say in your model you have a temperature value like

```
var temp: Int?
```

Then you can initialize it in your VC, and access the temp value

```
var model = Model()

let model.temp = inputTextField.text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `model.swift` for calculation. You will create an object of the model-class in the View controller, after creating an object you can pass the test field value to the model.

```
var modelObject: model? = model();
modelObject.temprature = txtTemprature.text;
```